# iPhone Is quartz leaking memory?

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics

I have been analyzing my application with instruments, and leaks is showing that I have single leak:

4 kb - malloc

responsabile library - QuartzCore

responsabile frame - CA::Transaction::create()

I have been wondering is this really quartz leaking, or i am mistaking this for something else?

Comment: You only have one framework leak? Awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. Apple frameworks aren't perfect, especially `QuartzCore` and other media-related frameworks. Don't fret - 'tis only 4K!